# Download an ics file as a subscription

Tags: c#, icalendar

I am trying to create an ics file that will create a subscription when downloaded and executed.
I am trying to import it into my outlook, but it only import once, and does not seem to be keeping up with changes.

It should of course work on desktop, Iphone, Ipad ect.

I am using Ical.Net and I am getting this ics file after I have downloaded it.

Filename: Somename.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
Name:Name
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
REFRESH-INTERVAL;VALUE=DURATION:PT30S //For fast updating
URL:http://localhost:7066/api/calendar/icsfeed/{Some code}
VERSION:2.0
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT30S
X-WR-CALNAME:
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20230509T172721Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230526
LOCATION:{LOCATION}
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Haveaffald
UID:ad37d9d6-c673-4c92-a0ac-4e434d7994c6
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20230509T172721Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230623
LOCATION:{LOCATION}
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Haveaffald
UID:86c74484-6203-4374-a814-051dc75f0979
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20230509T172721Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230721
LOCATION:{LOCATION}
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Haveaffald
UID:d77e3e98-b57d-45e5-b44c-43638804ec03
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure not all calendar applications implement this.

Comment: But those who does, how do they do it?

Comment: It looks like you want to refresh every 30s. That's probably not possible. Here it says that it might take up to 24 hours for outlook.com: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-com-cff1429c-5af6-41ec-a5b4-74f2c278e98c. Somewhere else I saw 48 hours for Google Calendar. I think you need to set more time aside for your test.